# removing many sites littered throughout a vector keeping memory cost minimal

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

I'm afraid this is a rather big question but here's the short version. My program needs to remove lots of elements scattered throughout a vector. Those elements relate to particles, and it also needs to tell any particles that have moved in the vector where they've moved to. Keeping memory costs low is the priority so ideally I hope to streamline this process whilst not altering my data structures (or shrinking them if i can).

Now the long version:

So I'm trying to make as efficient a program as i can that stores, in a number of bins (called categories here) a list of labels (which relate to particular particles) where each particle can be represented in only one category but may be represented many times (although not necessarily in neighbouring sites)

The categories have a list of which particles they contain (one element in the array per particle) and a list of which particles are contained in a particular site. (A site is the particular name I use throughout for array elements in this particular array) So the first might read (1,4,5), showing particles 1, 4 and 5 are in this category. The second might then read (4,5,1,1,4,4).

In order to do an inverted tree search the particles are seperately aware of where they sit in their categories list of particles and sites. (So 1 would know it was first in the list of particles and 3rd and 4th in the list of sites)

Ideally I don't want to add any more numbers stored by these data structures as minimising memory cost is my priority, but I will if I have to.

My problem is that removing all the elements corresponding to a certain particle is currently a very costly operation, but one that i have to do every step of the process, mostly due to having to find all the sites relating a to a particular particle as well as telling the other particles swapped with that their sites have moved around.

I currently send all the sites i want to remove to the back and pop them off, I can't see a better way of doing this.

Bear in mind that, whilst there are only 3 particles in the example, there may be millions in a real simulation.

Below are my data structures and the function i'm currently using to remove a particle from a category. The biggest cost by far at the moment is the reordering of all sites belonging to a certain particle to be in order of where they sit i the array of sites, the only reason i do this is so that i know any particle found near the back will be the in the last site of its list of sites.

Thankyou so much for any help, sorry this has turned into a huge question

(whichAtom is the particle label already picked and whichCategory is the category it's in)

```
struct particle
{
    float rate;
    int categorySite;
    vector<int> occupiedSites;
};

struct bin
{
    vector<int> atomsContained;
    vector<int> sites;
};

vector<struct particle> atom (NUMBER_OF_ATOMS);
vector<struct bin> category (10);

void removeAtom()
{
    //tells atom that was last in list of atoms in that category that it has changed position
    atom[category[whichCategory].atomsContained.back()].categorySite = atom[whichAtom].categorySite;

    //removes atom from list of atoms in that category
    category[whichCategory].atomsContained[atom[whichAtom].categorySite] = category[whichCategory].atomsContained.back();
    category[whichCategory].atomsContained.pop_back();

    int numberOfSites = (int) atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites.size();

    //removes sites from that category
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSites; i++)
    {
        if (atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites[i] != category[whichCategory].sites.size()-1)
        {
            int categorySize = (int) category[whichCategory].sites.size();
            int distanceFromBack = 1;
            while (category[whichCategory].sites[categorySize-distanceFromBack] == whichAtom && (categorySize-distanceFromBack) != atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites[i])
            {
                distanceFromBack++;
            }


            int originalSite = atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites[i];

            //teling the atom that it has changed site (requires last site listed in the atom to be the one nearest the back)
            int targetAtom = category[whichCategory].sites[categorySize-distanceFromBack];
            std::swap(atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites.back(), atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites[i]);

            // makes sure that the sites are refenced in the order they appear in the array
            if (atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites.size() > 1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites.size(); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = (int) atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites.size()-1; k > j; k--)
                    {
                        if (atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites[j] > atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites[k])
                        {
                            std::swap(atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites[j],atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //telling the category that the atoms in the sites have switched
            std::swap(category[whichCategory].sites[originalSite], category[whichCategory].sites[categorySize-distanceFromBack]);
        }
    }

    //removes previously occupied sites from atoms memory (MIGHT BE COMBINEABLE WITH ABOVE)
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSites; i++)
    {
        category[whichCategory].sites.pop_back();
        atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the ordering of particles within the `sites` array important?

Comment: Can you rephrase your text to be more complete (what are "elements" and "sites"?), more systematic and less wordy?

Comment: Make the long story short please

Comment: Tried to summarise the problem at the beginning but struggling to cut down the explanation. Ordering of particles within sites array completely unimportant. I use elements to describe individual units of an array, and sites in the particular case of elements of the big array where particles may be listed multiple times.

Comment: Adding to the complexity (and quite possibly the madness), is `atom`a vector of `particle`, and is `category` a vector of `bin`? Clarity on where those two variables come from and what they are *exactly* seems relevant, and providing it in-code may get you close to a sscce.

Comment: i won't argue with madness... but yes atom is the name of a particle structure and category of a bin

Comment: I ask because it would seem to me using an ordered `std::map<>` architecture would allow you to exploit the ordered-ness by using range-deleting. If a sequenced container ( vector, list, etc) is absolutely mandatory you would need to control insertion characteristics to insert in-order, but again, range-based deletes would be the end-win. I'm admit I still don't entirely understand your topology, but judging by the loops the double and triple-nested enumerations are your killer, and it is conceivable you can markedly reduce that if you can maintain an ordering in your collections.

Comment: @WhozCraig If I get it correctly, the OP's main aim to control memory consumption, and `std::map<>` would certainly be a killer in that respect, because it typically uses many small allocations, producing a lot of space overhead.

Comment: Like the others, I have not been able to grasp entirely what you want to do. However, I think, you should think about whether and how you can use intrusive linked lists to your advantage. They are heavily used in the Linux kernel, but are also available for user space programming. This link explains what they are, and how you can use them: http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/ Maybe that helps.

Comment: @cmaster I'm aware of the preconditions requested, as well as the concession from the OP: "I don't want to add any more numbers stored by these data structures as minimising memory cost is my priority, *but I will if I have to.*" Regardless, that is why i also mentioned maintaining a sort-ordered sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've found a simple rearrangement that improves it a lot without adding to memory costs.

Before i was ordering all the sites relating to the particle I wanted to remove at the end of the vector, then removing them all at once.

This was, basically, stupid. By starting with the last one (the for loop now counts down rather than up) I can remove them one by one, swapping with the last one, looking through it's list of sites to find the particular site i'm dealing with (rather than reordering them every time) then swapping everything around and removing the sites one by one.

Now my issue seems to be that the very act of removing sites from the vector (the pop_back at the end) is expensive. If anyone has any advice on this I'd love to know? The while loop is still the most time intensive part, but i'm not sure if it can be improved without just changing my structs.

Anyway, here's my code now (data structures the same as above)

```
void removeAtom()
{
    //tells atom that was last in list of atoms in that category that it has changed position
    atom[category[whichCategory].atomsContained.back()].categorySite = atom[whichAtom].categorySite;

    //removes atom from list of atoms in that category
    category[whichCategory].atomsContained[atom[whichAtom].categorySite] = category[whichCategory].atomsContained.back();
    category[whichCategory].atomsContained.pop_back();

    //works out number of sites to remove
    int numberOfSites = (int) atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites.size();

    //removes sites from that category, starting with the last one
    for (int i = numberOfSites; i > 0; i--)
    {
        //finds where the site we want to remove is, and where it will go (i.e. the end of the vector)
        int startingSite = atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites[i-1];
        int swappingSite = (int) (category[whichCategory].sites.size() - 1);

        //finds which atom is at the end, tells starting site that it's changed to this type
        int targetAtom = category[whichCategory].sites.back();
        category[whichCategory].sites[startingSite] = targetAtom;


        //finds where this site is in the list of sites that the target atom maintains
        int whichOccupiedSite = 0;
        int foundOccupiedSite = 0;

        while (foundOccupiedSite==0)
        {
            if (atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites[whichOccupiedSite] == swappingSite)
            {
                foundOccupiedSite = 1;
            }
            whichOccupiedSite++;
        }
        whichOccupiedSite--;

        //tells the atom it's moved site
        atom[targetAtom].occupiedSites[whichOccupiedSite] = startingSite;

        //removes this site
        category[whichCategory].sites.pop_back();
        atom[whichAtom].occupiedSites.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Also thanks to Ben who suggested using hash tables not vectors/arrays, probably would work great for the problem asked here, unfortunately elsewhere in the program i have to pick a particle from this vector of sites at random, such that the chance of picking it is weighted by the number of sites, which is easy with an array, but I can't see how to do it with a hash table?

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to advise against back-references of this sort (where particles remember their memberships), precisely because it tends to ossify the structure and make deletions more tedious. It may be faster for particles to remember only their categories, and manually scan through those arrays as necessary, than to also remember (and maintain as accurate data) where they are in those categories.

Comment: It would be great if I could do that but the arrays may have millions, even billions of elements so scanning through is just not an option.

Comment: Then they should be in hash tables, not arrays.

Comment: Aha, hash tables look like they might be just the thing, but can one reference call up multiple values? (e.g. if i told it i was looking for particle a, could it tell me the location of all n sites where particle a sits?)

Comment: Yes, some hash tables support this.

Comment: Excellent, and presumably, seeing as they seem to just be a more general version of an array, the memory cost is comparable and the time taken to find an element should actually be less?